# ruby - Sharing a class across modules

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming

I'm trying to mimic ActiveRecord with a simple set of ruby objects for running raw sql queries. Below is a spike I've been experimenting with:

```
module Runable
  def run
    return self::Results.new
  end
end

module Query
  class Results  
    def initialize
      @results = Object.find_by_sql()
    end

    def to_a
      #code
    end
  end
end

module Scored
  extend Runable
  include Query

  QUERY = 'a raw sql query string'
end

module Unseen
  extend Runable
  include Query

  QUERY = 'a different raw sql query string'
end
```

What I want to be able to do is create simple Modules for each type of raw sql query I'm going to run, put them into a file like `Scored` or `Unseen` above and call `.run` on them to get back a results object. So like this:

```
Scored.run #=> #<Scored::Results:0x0000000000>
Unseen.run #=> #<Unseen::Results:0x0000000000>
```

but instead I get this...

```
Scored.run #=> #<Query::Results:0x0000000000>
Unseen.run #=> #<Query::Results:0x0000000000>
```

I've been doing ruby and rails for over a year but I'm just beginning to get into more advanced ruby usage. This is my first big step into using modules and mixins.

The issue, as far as I can tell, is that module class methods have self scoped to the module they're defined in. So I get `Query::Results` because the initialize method for Results is defined in the Query module. That make sense?

Thank you for the help!

**Update 5/30 16:45**

Basically, I want to wrap a handful of raw SQL statements into modules like this:

```
module ScoredUsers
  include Queryable

  QUERY="SELECT * FROM users ..."
end
```

and interact with the queries like this:

```
r = ScoredUsers.run #=> ScoredUsers::Results
r.ids
r.load_objects
REDIS.zadd user:5:cache, r.to_a
```

I want to keep everything in modules and classes, the ruby way (I think?) so when I want to create a new query object I can simple use the boilerplate module like `Scored` above.

Comment: First and frequent question: what are you trying to achive? When you including some module with internal class into some other module, you are typically not getting new class (if you want to do so, you need some `included`-method magic). Try just `Scored::Results # => Query::Results` to better understand what's going on

Comment: I'm writing a handful of different SQL queries to populate an activity feed for our users. I want to wrap these in a module names after the query, with the ability to call `.run` on it and get back an object names QUERY_NAME::Results. Basically, I want to parrot how AR does this. This is also my first time practicing TDD so I started by writing a spec, then got stuck writing the code to fit the spec :)

Comment: So, can you please show the spec (some short code, maybe)? This way its a lot easier to fix the problem.

Comment: See my explaination above. I started to write the spec but stopped as soon as I couldn't figure out how to handle to `Scored.run #=> Scored::Results` spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting such a results is that class `Results` is created just once. When the module is included new constant is created within including class (`Scored::Results`), but it is pointing to same memory space as constant `Query::Results`.

What you need is that you have to create a new class for each class this module is being included in. This is perfect opportunity to use `included` method:

```
module Query
  def self.included(mod)
    results = Class.new do  
      def initialize
        @results = Object.find_by_sql()
      end

      def to_a
        #code
      end
    end
    mod.const_set('Results', results)        
  end
end
```

Now of course we are left with the question - do we really need to do this? This depends on how you are planning to use those classes.

Comment: do you think this makes sense given the update above?

Comment: this worked beautifully, and I understand the meta programming going on here. Thanks @BroiSatse. Now I'm just wondering if this is the best pattern for handling this situation.